# Is there an intuitive reason why variance of exponential distribution is $\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

Suppose that the estimated number of customers at a bank is $\lambda$ per unit time. If $X$ is a random variable of the number of customers per unit time, then $X$ has a distribution $\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$. Then, $\mathbb E(X) = \lambda$ and $\text{Var}(X) = \lambda$.

Conversely, if $Y$ is a random variable that measures wait time between two customers, then $Y$ has a distribution $\text{exp}(\lambda)$. Then, $\mathbb E(Y) = \frac{1}{\lambda}$ and $\text{Var}(Y) = \frac{1}{\lambda^2}$.

Of course, $\text{Var}(Y)$ can be calculated easily, but is there an intuitive reason that $\text{Var}(Y) = \frac{1}{\lambda^2}$ in relation to $\text{Var}(X) = \lambda$? Is it just a coincidence that $\text{Var}(Y) = \frac{1}{\text{Var}(X)^2}$?

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2092/relationship-between-poisson-and-exponential-distribution

Comment: $X$  is a random variable of the number of customers "in a particular unit of time" not "per unit time" since it is not an average.  Indeed it might make more sense to have $X$ as the number in a time interval length $t$ distributed $\text{Poisson}(\lambda t)$ with mean and variance $\lambda t$.  This is a consequence of the sum of independent Poissons being Poisson distributed.   Memorylessness makes the distribution of gaps in that interval exponential with expected gap $\frac{t}{\lambda t} =\frac1\lambda$ and the gap variance is proportional to its square because of shape invariance

Comment: That a PDF $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}1_{[0,\,\infty)}$ has variance of the form $c/\lambda^2$ for dimensionless $c$ is obvious from dimensional analysis, or substituting $y=\lambda x$. The hard (maybe impossible?) part to intuit, without calculation, is $c=1$.